# Configuring a Spring Security Filter Chain with a pattern returns 404 for /j_spring_security_check

Tags: spring-security

I am using spring MVC with Spring Security Release 3.1.3 with tomcat 7.0.37

I need to configure 2 Security Filter Chains, one for BasicAuthentication and one for FormBasedAuthentication.

Here is my spring-security.xml file:

```
<beans:beans ...>
...

<!-- ....................... -->
<!-- The Gui is secured here -->
<!-- ....................... -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" pattern="/gui/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/gui/login**" access="isAnonymous()"/>

    <form-login login-page="/gui/login" default-target-url="/gui/welcome"
                authentication-failure-url="/gui/loginfailed" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/gui/logout" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('een_admin')" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/mandantAdmin/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/standortAdmin/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/ereignisse/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/tickets/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>  <!-- requires-channel="https" -->        
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('een_admin')"/>
</http>

<!-- ................................. -->
<!-- The Service Methods are secured here -->
<!-- ................................. -->
<http use-expressions="true" >
    <http-basic />
    <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/service/ticketManagement/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/standortKonfig/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/service/ereignisStorage/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

</http>
<debug/>


<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <password-encoder hash="sha-256"/>
    <user-service>
        <user name="123" password="asdf" authorities="een_admin" />
    </user-service>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

My web.xml is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- ........................................................................... -->
<!--                                Spring Security                              -->
<!-- ........................................................................... -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When accessing one of the form-based protected resources i get successfully delegated to the configured custom login-form. But after entering my credentials I get an 404 error that the "j_spring_security_check" could not be found (it's using this url: `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/webapp/j_spring_security_check"`)

Here are some logs:

```
Request received for '/gui/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@174e4b3

servletPath:/gui/login
    pathInfo:null

    Security filter chain: [
      SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
      LogoutFilter
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
      BasicAuthenticationFilter
      RequestCacheAwareFilter
      SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
      AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
      SessionManagementFilter
      ExceptionTranslationFilter
      FilterSecurityInterceptor
    ]
    Request received for '/j_spring_security_check':

    org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@174e4b3

    servletPath:/j_spring_security_check
    pathInfo:null

    Security filter chain: [
      SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
      LogoutFilter
      BasicAuthenticationFilter
      RequestCacheAwareFilter
      SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
      AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
      SessionManagementFilter
      ExceptionTranslationFilter
      FilterSecurityInterceptor
    ]

    01:06:06,345  WARN http-apr-8080-exec-3 servlet.PageNotFound:1080 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/webapp/j_spring_security_check] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

    In access_logs:
    "POST /webapp/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 404 949
```

Note the missing **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter** when redirecting.

If I remove the pattern attribute pattern="/gui/**" in the first  Element and comment out the second  Element (needed as otherwise there is an issue with the interceptor-url patterns) it works fine again.

Simplified a little: When adding a pattern attribute to the http element  j_spring_security_check cannot be found anymore.

What am I doing wrong, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to realise that the URLs you define within an `http` block are *not* relative to the `pattern` attribute, so for a start, all the `intercept-url` patterns you have, such as `/welcome*` will have no effect, since they will only be activated for URLs which start with `/gui` and hence will never match. It should be `/gui/welcome`.

The URL your login form is submitted to must also have a matching `form-login` element somewhere. In your case it is within the `/gui/**` filter chain, hence the request for `/j_spring_security_check` will never be matched.

So you need to change the URL in your login form to start with `/gui`. You can also modify the URL which the filter responds to by setting the [`login-processing-url`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login). For example:

```
<form-login login-processing-url="/gui/login.do" login-page="/gui/login" default-target-url="/gui/welcome" authentication-failure-url="/gui/loginfailed" />
```

(It's a good idea to choose something which doesn't mention Spring at all).

You should also remove the `auto-config` attribute as it isn't doing anything useful here and just confuses people.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you realy helped me out on this!

Comment: I used "/gui/j_spring_security_check" as the login-processing-url, the same value my login.jsp sends its data to, and it works now. I didn't quite get though how to use this "login.do", where does the “j_spring_security_check” kick in then?

Comment: It is no longer relevant. `login-processing-url` sets the URL which the filter responds to and, as long as it matches the one in your login form, it doesn't matter what is is. `/j_spring_security_check` is just the default value.